# How to establish connection to the neo4j graph database in javascript with js2neo driver

Tags: neo4j

I get this error when i try to use the connection

WebSocket connection to 'ws://bolt//localhost:7687' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Downloaded neo4j desktop
started the browser and added a local graph database.

Downloaded the js2neo driver

```
<script src="js/js2neo.min.js"></script>
```

connected to the database as per http://js2neo.org/

```
var cx = js2neo.open({ host: "bolt://localhost", user: "neo4j", 
password: "1234567890!" })
```

test the content of the database

```
cx.run("MATCH (n) RETURN *", { onRecord: console.log })
```

Comment: is your neo4j running, try running the command `neo4j console` by navigating under bin folder

Answer (score 0):

Your host configuration is not good (it's `host` not `url`).

So instead of

```
var cx = js2neo.open({ host: "bolt://localhost", user: "neo4j", 
password: "1234567890!" })
```

do this :

```
var cx = js2neo.open({ host: "localhost", user: "neo4j", 
password: "1234567890!" })
```